# sharing Joomla URL on Facebook - editing picture, title and description

Tags: joomla-user-groups

i have a handful of Joomla sites that i manage ranging from version 1.5 all the way to the recent version, 3.3. whenever i go to share a link from one of my sites on Facebook (no matter what Joomla version), the thumbnail, title and description does not reflect the information contained on the page i want to share.

i have seen a lot of information regarding the use of open-graph (OG) meta tags, but i am not sure as to how to implement them into the Joomla structure.

any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

this is a different approach for the requirement, Many times the OG tags creates issue for sharing image URL on FB, due to cache,compression etc.
So in any CMS its better to use `Javascript SDK for FB` share to share custom image,title ,description etc.

The issue with cache or compression and conflict with `OG tags` will get solved with this method.

Just Create an APP on FB.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'APP ID',                            
      status     : true,                                 
      xfbml      : true                                  
    });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function FBShareOp(){
    var product_name   =    'your title name';
    var description    =    'description';
    var share_image    =    'full image url ';
    var share_url      =    'url to share'; 
        var share_capt     =    'caption';
    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: product_name,
        link: share_url,
        picture: share_image,
        caption: share_capt,
        description: description

    }, function(response) {
        if(response && response.post_id){}
        else{}
    });

}

</script>
```

for more details of [Custom Share button on FB](http://www.walkswithme.net/facebook-share-button-with-custom-parameters)

hope it make sense.

Comment: this worked like a charm, thank you! (extremely late reply, lol)

Answer (score 4):

I would first use Facebook's debugging tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

If nothing is populating, these are possible causes:
1. GZip
2. Compression Tools in Template
3. 3rd Party Plugins (Rokbooster, JCH Optimize)

If you have a newer Rockettheme template, look in the index.php as they have some meta OG tags pre-defined.

Here is a good guide to open-graph (OG) meta tags if you want to add them to your template's index.php file:
http://moz.com/blog/meta-data-templates-123